# How to understand stationary solution?

Tags: measure-theory, limits, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

How to understand the `stationary solution` of the stochatic equation: 
$$X_{n+1}=A_n X_n+B_n$$

And where can I find more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is stationary *in distribution*, that is, one looks for a distribution $\mu$ such that, if $(A,B)$ is distributed like every $(A_n,B_n)$ and if $X$ is independent of $(A,B)$ and with distribution $\mu$, then the distribution of $AX+B$ is $\mu$ as well.

Equivalently, $\mu$ is a fixed point of the transformation of the space $\mathcal M_1^+$ of probability measures which sends any distribution of a random variable $X$ to the distribution of $AX+B$, with the independence assumptions explained above.

In the present case, $\mu$ should be the distribution of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i\right)\cdot B_k,
$$
provided that this series converges almost surely (a condition which imposes that some hypotheses on the distribution of $A$ are met).

Section 2 of the paper *[Iterated Random Functions](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036144598338446)* by Persi Diaconis and David Freedman is a classic on the subject.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately my school doesn't buy this database, could you share this paper with me, [mailto:qsu926@gmail.com](mailto:qsu926@gmail.com), thank you again!

Comment: [No need to](http://oz.berkeley.edu/tech-reports/511.pdf).